# div expand height & with variable width

Tags: css

Heres the scenario ,

i am going for a full page layout on a responsive site .

i have a left bar ( a ) and a right section ( b ) sitting in container ( c )

a ) will be 30% of width - max-width 480px ; must expand to fill container height ( c )

b ) needs to sit to the right of ( a ) ; must expand to fill container height ( c ) and width

```
<div id="con">
 <div id="a"></div>
 <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#c { }

#a {
    float : left;
    width: 30%;
    max-width : 480px;
    height: 100%;
}

#b {
    background-color: #DDD;
    margin-left : 480px; 
    /* make it work with any margin left as it wont always be 480  */
    margin-right : 0;
}
```

With that css ( a ) is not expanding to fit (c ) and ( b ) is only working because i have set margin-left to 480 but it wont be that in most cases it will be 30% of page width . 
can i achieve this in css or should use jquery ?

Comment: I guess that your issue lies with (c) not having any pre-defined dimensions. Is this the case?

Comment: Mr_Green gave already a working answer. Here is just another way to achieve it :) http://jsfiddle.net/duFfZ/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: table-cell` to both `a` and `b` container.  Something like this:

```
.c{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;  /* mention some height */
}

.a {
    width: 30%;
    max-width: 480px;
}

.a, .b {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/Hg98D/)**

Answer (score 1):

You may use table behaviors to achieve this.

Here is working [SAMPLE.](http://codepen.io/qtgye/pen/JEfDH)

CSS:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#con {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
   display:table;
  background: #00f;
}   

#a, #b {
  display: table-cell;
}

#a{    
    width: 30%;
    max-width : 480px;
    height: 100%;
}


#b{

    background-color: #DDD; 



}
```